# Why is the for loop with show/hide not working in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created for loop which works but for some reason the show/hide part does not work and no matter what I just can't figure out why.

```
<div id="app">

  <ul>
    <li v-for="club in clubs" v-on:click="toggleDetails(clubs)">
      <h1>{{club.name}}</h1>
      <div v-show="clubs.showDetail">
          <p>{{club.location}}</p>
          <p>{{club.members}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and for the JS part I have the following;

```
const clubs = [
    {
   name: 'Tigers',
   location: 'Manchester',
   members: '22'
    },
    {
   name: 'Dolphins',
   location: 'Miami',
   members: '19'
    },
    {
   name: 'Bleu Sox',
   location: 'Paris',
   members: '13'
    } 
];

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Here is a list',
    club: clubs
  },
  methods: {
        toggleDetails: function(clubs) {
        clubs.showDetail = !clubs.showDetail;
    }  
  }
});
```

Comment: It's weird to set an attribute to an array. And also it's [certainly not reactive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) if you add it in that way. Why not add a property directly to data to control the visibility?

Comment: Do you mean remove the club: clubs from the data: part?

Comment: I mean `data: { showClubDetails: true, ... }` and then for `toggleDetails` `this.showClubDetails = !this.showClubDetails`.

Comment: Like this then https://codepen.io/Al-V/pen/maZzrQ?editors=1010

Comment: Like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwBwMp?editors=1010. Need to change `v-show="showClubDetails"`

Comment: I have updated mine as suggested and it now works. Thank you very much. The way had mine as above was taken from Treehouse. It was odd as the code was exactly the same, no errors, but just didnt work. However, all sorted now thanks to your help. Much appricitaed.

Comment: Actually it still opens all and not 'this' :(

Comment: Added an answer below -

Answer (score 3):

If you need to show detail on each club separately, you need to set a property on each club separately instead of on `clubs`; Also use `Vue.set` to reactively add a new property to an object as follows:

```js
const clubs = [
    {
   name: 'Tigers',
   location: 'Manchester',
   members: '22'
    },
    {
   name: 'Dolphins',
   location: 'Miami',
   members: '19'
    },
    {
   name: 'Bleu Sox',
   location: 'Paris',
   members: '13'
    } 
];

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Here is a list',
    clubs
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDetails: function(club) {
      this.$set(club, 'showDetails', !club.showDetails)
    }  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="club in clubs" v-on:click="toggleDetails(club)">
      <h1>{{club.name}}</h1>
      <div v-show="club.showDetails">
          <p>{{club.location}}</p>
          <p>{{club.members}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```